# I need to make an alert box that shows what user entered in comment section

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why this code won't work. I need a simple solution. This is just a college project and it doesn't have to do more then just following:
I want to make ti so that when someone enters their name, location and eaddress, gender and comment alert box pops up with this kind of form:

```
Name, Location, eAddress, Gender
comment...
```

**Code:**

```
<div style="font-family:'Cinzel';text-align:center;">
    Ime: <input type="text" name="Ime" value=""><br></br>
    Lokacija: <input type="text" name="Lokacija" value=""></br><br>
    E Adresa: <input type="text" name="eAdresa" value=""></br><br>
 <form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Muško
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Žensko
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Drugo<br>
  <button onclick="Ispis()">Pošalji</button>
</form> 
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Komentar" form="usrform" placeholder="Ostavite komentar..."></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    function Ispis(){
        var Ime=getElementsByName=("Ime")[0].value;
        var lokacija=getElementsByName=("Lokacija")[0].value;
        var eAdresa=getElementsByName=("eAdresa")[0].value;
        var Pol=getElementsByName=("gender")[0].value;
alert(Ime+","+Lokacija+","+eAdresa+","+Gender+"<br>"+Komentar);
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: No, it's just not doing anything.

Comment: You named the variable `lokacija`, but then tried to use `Lokacija` in your value concatenation - variable names in JavaScript are case sensitive! Please go make it a habit to _always_ check your browser console for errors first of all.

Comment: Secondly, your button is a _submit button_, so it will submit this form once you click it. You either need to prevent that default action, or make your button a click button to begin with (`type="button"`)

Comment: And `Gender` is not defined either, you named the variable you read the value of that input field into `Pol` … pay a little more attention to what you are actually doing. And `Komentar` is not defined either …

Comment: why is there an `=` here: getElementsByName=("Ime")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- the form instantly gets submitted when clicking on a button, you can make an input with button type that will not submit automatically
- `lokacija=document.getElementsByName("Lokacija")[0].value` needs document. and doesn't need = after getElementsByName
- few missing variables, javascript variable names are case sensitive
- in the alert box, you can use "\n" for line break (new line)
- to correctly handle selected radio buttons, you can use the `:checked` queryselector like so: `var Gender = document.querySelector('[name="gender"]:checked').value`

```js
function Ispis(){
  var Ime = document.getElementsByName("Ime")[0].value;
  var lokacija = document.getElementsByName("Lokacija")[0].value;
  var Gender = document.getElementsByName("gender")[0].value;
  var Gender = document.querySelector('[name="gender"]:checked').value;
  var eAdresa = document.getElementsByName("eAdresa")[0].value;
  var Komentar = document.getElementsByName("Komentar")[0].value;
  alert(Ime+","+lokacija+","+eAdresa+","+Gender+"\n"+Komentar);
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family:'Cinzel';text-align:center;">
    Ime: <input type="text" name="Ime" value=""><br><br>
    Lokacija: <input type="text" name="Lokacija" value=""><br><br>
    E Adresa: <input type="text" name="eAdresa" value="">
 <form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Muško
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Žensko
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Drugo<br>
  <input type="button" onclick="Ispis()" value="alert!">
</form> 
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Komentar" form="usrform" placeholder="Ostavite komentar..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @misteroggy if this answer helped you, make sure you up vote it!  If it provided your solution, you can also click the grey checkmark below the voting icons to mark it as the one that worked for you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of the button that is submitting your form try out to put

```
<input type="button" onclick="Ispis()" value="Yourtext">
```

then rename your variables with lowercase, it's case sensitive

Comment: @MisterOggy then put it as an input

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors, here a working version:

```js
function Ispis() {
  var ime = document.getElementsByName("ime")[0].value;
  var lokacija = document.getElementsByName("lokacija")[0].value;
  var eAdresa = document.getElementsByName("eadresa")[0].value;
  var pol = document.getElementsByName("gender")[0].value;
  var komentar = document.getElementsByName("komentar")[0].value;
  alert(ime + "," + lokacija + "," + eAdresa + "," + pol + "<br>" + komentar);
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family:'Cinzel';text-align:center;">
  <form>
    Ime: <input type="text" name="ime" value=""><br> Lokacija: <input type="text" name="lokacija" value=""><br> E Adresa: <input type="text" name="eadresa" value=""><br>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Muško
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Žensko
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Drugo<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="Ispis()">Pošalji</button>
  </form>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="komentar" form="usrform" placeholder="Ostavite komentar..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Written using ES6:

```js
(function () {
  const getValueFromElement = name => document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value

  const ispis = () => {
    const ime = getValueFromElement("ime");
    const lokacija = getValueFromElement("lokacija");
    const eAdresa = getValueFromElement("eadresa");
    const pol = getValueFromElement("gender");
    const komentar = getValueFromElement("komentar");
    alert(`${ime},${lokacija},${eAdresa},${pol},<br>${komentar}`)
  }

  const button = document.getElementById('button')
  button.addEventListener('click', () => ispis())
}());
```

```html
<div style="font-family:'Cinzel';text-align:center;">
  <form>
    Ime: <input type="text" name="ime" value=""><br> Lokacija: <input type="text" name="lokacija" value=""><br> E Adresa: <input type="text" name="eadresa" value=""><br>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Muško
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Žensko
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Drugo<br>
    <button id="button" type="button">Pošalji</button>
  </form>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="komentar" form="usrform" placeholder="Ostavite komentar..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @MisterOggy please do not forget to accept an answer by clicking the V icon next to your question :) thanks (and welcome into SO)!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as below to work...

```
<div style="font-family:'Cinzel';text-align:center;">
    Ime: <input type="text" name="Ime" value=""><br></br>
    Lokacija: <input type="text" name="Lokacija" value=""></br><br>
    E Adresa: <input type="text" name="eAdresa" value=""></br><br>
 <form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Muško
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Žensko
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Drugo<br>
  <button onclick="Ispis()">Pošalji</button>
</form> 
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Komentar" form="usrform" placeholder="Ostavite komentar..."></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    function Ispis(){
        var Ime=document.getElementsByName("Ime")[0].value;
        var lokacija=document.getElementsByName("Lokacija")[0].value;
        var eAdresa=document.getElementsByName("eAdresa")[0].value;
        var Gender=document.getElementsByName("gender")[0].value;
        var Komentar=document.getElementsByName("Komentar")[0].value;
        debugger
        alert(Ime+","+lokacija+","+eAdresa+","+Gender+"\n"+Komentar);
}
</script>
```